# Center UIview vertically inside UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, vertical-alignment

How to vertically center UIviews inside UItableViewCell?

I want to center UIButton vertically inside the UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of Googling , I found the answer in the blog post [a link](http://tentakel.dk/2011/07/28/Centering-subview-in-UITableViewCell.html)

This will center the UIView horizontally

```
myAwesomeSubView.center = cell.contentView.center;
```

This is the right solution

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews)
    {
        view.center = self.contentView.center;
    }
}
```